OneToOne Java persistence duplications
I have this structure:
Entity1 -> 
    Entity2 ->
        Entity3 

Performing save for Entity1 with letting persistence to save both, parent and child.
Entity 3 is already saved in DB, before Entity1 and Entity2.
So when I save Entity2, first I get Entity3 and set it:
// Entity2 class
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, optional=false, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private Entity3 entity3;

Then perform saving Entity2:
    // entity3 is get form DB
    entity2.setEntity3(entity3);
    return entityManager().create(entity2);

Once that is set, Entity1 is being created.
Problem:
When I create Entity2, even if I set entity3 from DB, it creates new object with new ID.
So I have duplicated objects instead just to have the same...
I have tried:

used entityManger().merge(entity3). -> performs update and make it persistence (double check)
perform entity2 save, then update with entity3 set
checked equals method in Entity3, its based in PK

Any idea?

Show the entities - exactly how you are creating your Entity1, 2 and 3 objects for the 'save' that is causing duplicates would also help.  The only way I can see this happening is if the entity3 instance you are using does NOT have an ID set - how are you getting this object exactly? If following the solution below, maybe try using find before calling merge, or just use the instance returned from find to manually merge changes into the managed entity3 yourself. Also check what you are 'saving' with entity1 and that it doesn't have some other entity2'/entity3' data referenced.

Also, why does everyone insist on implementing equals/hashcode? Don't use equals based on mutable fields. The ID will be null when it is a new object, so you risk have two 'new' entities showing as equal when maybe they aren't. Probably not the issue here, but could be if you are relying on it to tell if two instances are the same - especially in sets. Maybe try calling flush before you 'save' entity 2 to verify all managed changes are cleared, then do your save entity2 logic with another flush to ensure it really is your entity2 graph causing the insert.
